# PrimePush chat is not working

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, primepush

my target is on page load to subscribe two users in chat (teacher and student), and they can send messages to each others, so here's what i did:

**1- BackingBean:**

```
package com.myapp.beans;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.push.PushContext;
import org.primefaces.push.PushContextFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.xeno.xenoTemplate.utils.constants.Pages;

@Component("chatBean")
@Scope("view")
@URLMapping(id = Pages.CHAT, pattern = "/chat", viewId = "/faces/pages/users/chat.xhtml")
public class ChatView {

    private final PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault()
            .getPushContext();

    private String privateMessage;

    private String privateUser;

    private final static String CHANNEL = "/chat/";

    private String student = "student";

    private String teacher = "teacher";

    private boolean pageLoaded;

    private boolean studentLoggedIn;

    private boolean teacherLoggedIn;

    public void preRender() {
        System.out.println("########### preRender CHAT BEAN #########");
        if (!pageLoaded) { // invoked first time page loaded
            System.out.println("########### Invoking PreRender Code #########");
            if (!studentLoggedIn) {
                System.out.println("########## STUDENT LOG IN ##########");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
                        "subscriber.connect('/" + student + "')");
                studentLoggedIn = true;
            }
            if (!teacherLoggedIn) {
                System.out.println("########## TEACHER LOG IN ##########");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
                        "subscriber.connect('/" + teacher + "')");
                teacherLoggedIn = true;
            }
            pageLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    public void sendPrivate() {
        System.out.println("######### SEND PRIVATE ##########");
        pushContext.push(CHANNEL + privateUser, "[PM] " + "PRIVATE" + ": "
                + privateMessage);
        privateMessage = null;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setStudent(String student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudentLoggedIn(boolean studentLoggedIn) {
        this.studentLoggedIn = studentLoggedIn;
    }

    public boolean isStudentLoggedIn() {
        return studentLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setTeacherLoggedIn(boolean teacherLoggedIn) {
        this.teacherLoggedIn = teacherLoggedIn;
    }

    public boolean isTeacherLoggedIn() {
        return teacherLoggedIn;
    }

    public String getPrivateUser() {
        return privateUser;
    }

    public void setPrivateUser(String privateUser) {
        this.privateUser = privateUser;
    }

    public String getPrivateMessage() {
        return privateMessage;
    }

    public void setPrivateMessage(String privateMessage) {
        this.privateMessage = privateMessage;
    }

}
```

and in the **JSF page**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Chat</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="/pages/template/commonLayout.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{chatBean.preRender}" />

            <h:form id="form">

                <p:fieldset id="container" legend="PrimeChat" toggleable="true">

                    <h:panelGroup>

                       <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="publicColumn,usersColumn"
                            style="width:400px;">

                       <p:outputPanel style="height: 100px;" id="public" layout="block"
                                styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-widget-content chatlogs" />

                       <h:panelGroup id="users" styleClass="usersList">

                                <p:commandButton id="private_send" title="Chat" icon="ui-icon-comment"
                                    oncomplete="pChat.show()" update=":form:privateChatContainer">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{chatBean.student}"
                                        target="#{chatBean.privateUser}" />
                                </p:commandButton>
                        #{chatBean.student}
                        </h:panelGroup>

                        </h:panelGrid>



                    </h:panelGroup>


                </p:fieldset>

                <!-- Private Chat Dialog -->
                <p:dialog widgetVar="pChat" header="Private Chat" modal="true"
                    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                    <h:panelGrid id="privateChatContainer" columns="2"
                        columnClasses="vtop,vtop">
                        <p:outputLabel for="pChatInput"
                            value="To: #{chatBean.privateUser}" />
                        <p:inputTextarea id="pChatInput"
                            value="#{chatBean.privateMessage}" rows="5" cols="30" />

                        <p:spacer />
                        <p:commandButton value="Send"
                            actionListener="#{chatBean.sendPrivate}"
                            oncomplete="pChat.hide()" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>

            </h:form>

            <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/chat"
                autoConnect="false" widgetVar="subscriber" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function handleMessage(data) {
                    alert('handleMessage');
                    var chatContent = $(PrimeFaces
                            .escapeClientId('form:public'));
                    chatContent.append(data + '<br />');
                    chatContent.scrollTop(chatContent.height());
                }
            </script>



        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 

  <display-name>MyAPP</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationSecurity.xml
        </param-value>

  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/utils.taglib.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>





  <!--  -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>


   <filter>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping> 

  <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--  
    <filter>
      <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>ERROR</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->

    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
     <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
     <location>/error</location>
  </error-page>

   <error-page>
     <error-code>400</error-code>
     <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>

   <error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/pageNotFound</location>
   </error-page>

   <!-- PrimePush Servlet -->

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
          <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
          <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
          <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>    
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

i am using the **following jars**:

1. JSF 2.1.10
2. PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT
3. Tomcat 7.0.32
4. atmosphere-runtime 1.0.1

**HEADERS**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/MyAPP/chat
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:282
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=2BB4298A4E291CCCBB80EE3A4A5624BC
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/PrimeTemplate/chat
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:form:j_idt31
javax.faces.partial.execute:@all
form:j_idt31:form:j_idt31
form:form
form:j_idt24:
form:container_collapsed:false
form:pChatInput:aaaaaaaaaaaa
javax.faces.ViewState:5079906166114901626:-433970771510989466
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:190
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 18 Oct 2012 10:40:04 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[5079906166114901626:-433970771510989466]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

**ISSUE:**

i can open the chat window for the student and type a chat message then press enter, the code gets in the `sendPrivate` bean method, but the JS `handleMessage` function is not called and hence the private message is not displayed in the JSF page, i get no errors in browser console.

please advise how to fix that.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Why do you use such an outdated Version of PF? And then also a Snapshot?

Comment: @Thor, it's the latest version of primefaces ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Oh, sorry. My fault. mixed this with 3.4 ... of course you are right!

Comment: Try disabling Pretty Faces for a while.

Comment: @Piotr Gwiazda, i removed the mapping for this page, and tried to access it with the classic way with full url, but i get the same behavior.

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious for you and that's why it's not mentioned in the question. Do you have two sessions/browsers opened? A private message sent from *student* to *teacher* will be displayed on teacher's chat only. It will not appear on student's.

Comment: @Piotr Gwiazda, i want to make this chat like facebook when sending a message it appears for both sender and receiver.

Comment: Does it show on receiver screen now? Adding text to sender screen should be simple. Just replace `pChat.hide()` in Send commandButton with suitable JS code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following jars to your lib folder (if you havent already done that):

atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.1.jar

atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.1.jar

Also have in mind that if you are connected as STUDENT to the "student" channel and if you are  pushing message to "teacher" channel, only teacher's channel will receive a message.

To test your chat, you need to login as student in one browser and as teacher in another browser. In this case, when you push message as student to the teacher in one browser, teacher in another browser will receive the message.